# Django auto fill recipient in Django_messages

Tags: python, django, autofill, django-messages

I'm building a job board and I'm using django_messages for private messages.
It works great but I want to auto fill the recipient form field with the username and I don't know why.

Some thoughts?

This is the view which I have candidates that applied for a job position. When I click send message, I need to auto fill the recipient field.

```
#views.py
class Screening(generic.DetailView):

    model = Job
    template_name = 'dashboard/screening.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Screening, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['candidate_list'] = self.object.applied_to.all().order_by('candidate')
        return context  

 #in the template
 {% for candidate in candidate_list %}
     {% candidate %}
     <a href="">Send message to this candidate</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

The models

```
#models.py
class Candidate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    birth = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class Job(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ManyToManyField('Candidate', through='CandidateToJob')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...

class CandidateToJob(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='applied_to')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, related_name='from_user')
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ('1', 'Not approved'),
       ('2', 'Approved'),
       ('3', 'Hired')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("candidate", "job")
```

The django_messages app view to send messages

```
   def compose(request, recipient=None, form_class=ComposeForm,
    template_name='djangomessages/compose.html', success_url=None, recipient_filter=None):

    if request.method == "POST":
        sender = request.user
        form = form_class(request.POST, recipient_filter=recipient_filter)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(sender=request.user)
            messages.info(request, _(u"Message successfully sent."))
            if success_url is None:
                success_url = reverse('messages_inbox')
            if 'next' in request.GET:
                success_url = request.GET['next']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
    else:
        form = form_class()
        if recipient is not None:
            recipients = [u for u in User.objects.filter(**{'%s__in' % get_username_field(): [r.strip() for r in recipient.split('+')]})]
            form.fields['recipient'].initial = recipients
    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the model in django_messages app

```
class Message(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(_("Subject"), max_length=120)
    body = models.TextField(_("Body"))
    sender = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='sent_messages', verbose_name=_("Sender"))
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='received_messages', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Recipient"))
```

Comment: What does your form_class look like?

Comment: Thanks, it was solved as showed in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817483/django-cannot-assign-uusername-message-recipient-must-be-a-user-instanc?noredirect=1#comment42205692_26817483